# Mature C++ interpreter on macOS

Tags: c++, programming, macos

I have a bunch of files that I constantly need to apply some operations on, like renaming, or video and sound editing using **ffmpeg**. For those tasks I normally write a **bash** script with what ever snippet of code I can find, but then I end up googling the same stuff over and over due to the cryptic syntax of the language constructs and also because of commands like **sed**, **awk**, and friends.

Then there is **Python**, which I use for web scraping and data processing. But what I really want is to script in **C++** for the two use cases, either for simple tasks that I normally use **bash** for, and also for web scraping and data processing.

Is there some **C++** interpreter for **macOS** mature enough?

I'm not interested in writing my own C++ interpreter, but rather I'd like something like **[Cling](https://root.cern.ch/cling)**.

I tried **Cling** a while back but, back then, the interpreter felt more like a hack than something that on could add to the work flow for everyday use. I wanted to try it again these days but it isn't available on **homebrew** yet, so I decided to ask for an alternative first.

Comment: It's not clear where C++ comes in here. Do you want a script interpreter that's _implemented_ in C++, or do you want to interpret C++? The first part of your answer suggests the former, the Cling example suggests the latter.

Comment: @einpoklum edited the question, thanks for pointing that out.